# Install4j installer facing bigger font size issue on linux RHEL 6.4

Tags: install4j

We are using install4j for to build our installer. We are facing bigger font size issue on linux RHEL 6.4.

On Linux RHEL 64, installer showing bigger font then windows which in turns to  UI issue (i.e. form controls not aligned to each other etc). Is there any option in install4j that on linux we can have same look and feel or is there any property which install4j provide and can be set to avoid bigger font size issue on linux RHEL 6.4.

Thanks, 
Jignesh

Comment: Do you have a standard license for install4J?  ej-technologies supports installation problems for the first 60 days after purchase.  See [http://www.ej-technologies.com/support/information.html](http://www.ej-technologies.com/support/information.html).

Comment: Yes we have license for install4j. I already filled Ticket#10102961 and communicated but I didn't get satisfactory solution and so still I am trying to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Different systems include different fonts by defaults. Those fonts do not have necessarily the same metrics (letter size). Linux systems often default to Dejavu which *is* slightly larger than Arial (usual windows default). And btw OS editors are constrained by font licensing agreements and even when they do bundle the same fonts they don't bundle the same versions nor use the same font rendering engines so that's unlikely to change in the future.

The moral being, don't use designs that rely on constant letter sizes for cross-platform apps. They will fail horribly sooner rather than later. (even ignoring new tech like hidpi). If your widgets do not adapt to text size, with proper grid fitting, you lose.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with your comments. But here in case of install4j how we can handle font issue for Linux. We are decreasing our font size for Linux still facing bigger font size issue.